# Limit list of apps user can launch?

Tags: security, permission

In Windows it is possible to configure system so, that user runs only some list of applications (for example Word, Excel, PowerPoint...) and user can't launch anything else.

How can I configure OS X the same way? (For example permit to launch office applications, Mail, Safari and forbid to launch any other application).

Answer (score 5):

Parental Controls allows you to limit the applications that the user can use.

This [knowledge base article](http://support.apple.com/kb/PH11354?viewlocale=en_US) from Apple shows how to set up parental controls on a per user basis.

[This article](http://support.apple.com/kb/PH10907?viewlocale=en_US) goes into the specifics of limiting apps that the user can use.

The basics are:

**Restrict other apps a user can open**

1. Choose Apple menu > System Preferences, and then click Parental Controls.
2. Click the lock if it’s not unlocked, and enter an administrator name and password.
3. Select a user in the list of users, and then click Apps.
4. Select Limit Applications.
5. In the Allowed Apps list, select any category whose apps you want to view, and then click the disclosure triangle to list the apps in the category. To search for an app, enter its name in the search field.
6. Select the checkbox for each app you want to let the user open.